# sequence in $l^p$ which is not in $l^q$ for $q<p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Does there exist a sequence $(x_n)$ such that for some $p$ one has $(x_n)\in l^p$, but $(x_n)\notin l^q$ for all $q<p$?

Any explicit example or reference would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a_n=\frac 1 {n^{1/p}(\ln\, n)^{2})^{1/p}}$ (for $n>1$) is such a sequence.

Comment: How does one prove this?

Comment: Use integral test.

Comment: Cauchy Condensation Test........+1